# Django syntax error in python 2.7.4

Tags: python, django

i'm a complete noob on django... i think i just installed  it right on ubunto!
I'm using python 2.7.4 and the latest version of django

when i try to import it from the python shell i got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "django.py", line 2
django-admin.py startproject mysite
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas on wwhat i might be doing wrong ? thanks !!!

any ideas ? ,,, thanks !

Comment: This is a command for the command line, not for the python shell.

Answer (score 1):

What you are *trying* to do is input a command line command into the Python Console. Lets take a look at your command:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

## #1 `django-admin.py`

---

As you can guess, this looks like a file name, and it is a file. In fact, it is a script that can take in arguments like `startproject`.

## #2 `startproject`

---

This is a command that you can pass to `django-admin.py` in the command line to start a new project.

## #3 `mysite`

---

The name of your site.

[From the docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)

> From the command line, cd into a directory where you’d like to store your code, then run the following command:

Answer (score 0):

From Django documentation:

> Creating a project
>
> If this is your first time using Django, you’ll have to take care of
>   some initial setup. Namely, you’ll need to auto-generate some code
>   that establishes a Django project – a collection of settings for an
>   instance of Django, including database configuration, Django-specific
>   options and application-specific settings.
>
> From the command line, cd into a directory where you’d like to store
>   your code, then run the following command:
>
> django-admin.py startproject mysite

Please refer to [Writing your first Django app part 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)

It's very easy and it will surly help.